# how could I use different `.vimrc` with `-u` option

Tags: vimrc, options

I have configured my `.vimrc` to make my vim work, and then I renamed my `.vimrc` to be `.vimrc2`. After that my vim can run as clean mode, but when I run my vim with `vim -u .vimrc2`, there are errors like this:

```
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
line   59:
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
line   60:
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
line   61:
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
line   73:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
E15: Invalid expression: pathogen#infect()
```

How could I make it work? My `.vimrc2` works well if it is renamed to be `.vimrc` and no `-u` options are used.

Edit:

my vimrc is here: https://github.com/CoinCheung/learn-coding-notes/blob/master/vim/00-vimrc

Comment: Can you post the contents of this vimrc? See also `help -u`: some initializations are skipped and compatible will be set (which you should disable in your vimrc)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks, see my updates for vimrc please.

Comment: If the file `$HOME/.vimrc` exists, Vim switches to `nocompatible` and then sources the file. By giving the file with `-u .vimrc2` the file is sourced in compatible mode. So you should add `set nocompatible` at the beginning of that file.See `:help .vimrc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim will automatically set `nocompatible` when loading `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/vimrc`. But it's *not* set automatically when loading a file with the `-u` option, or using `:source`.

The solution is to add `set nocompatible` to the `.vimrc2` file, or use the `-N` flag to set it (`vim -N -u .vimrc2`).

Personally I think it's always a good idea to add `set nocompatible` to vimrc files exactly to avoid this confusion, even if it's not strictly needed when loading from the default locations. But some people are dead-set against it ‍

Comment: Another option is an `if &compatible` guard

Comment: `set nocompatible` also worked for me but I don't understand why?
I installed a new vundle package `hashi-vim/vim-terraform` for Terraform syntax highlighting so it must be something to do with this. Anyway, I don't seem to be loosing anything by being in `nocompatible` mode for now but if anyone has any insights, that would be great!